# What is the correct way to reference a sub-class of a PHP package when using Composer?

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

I have an application running in CakePHP 3 and have installed my packages via Composer.

Most recently I added `phpspec/php-diff` (https://packagist.org/packages/phpspec/php-diff) and ran `composer update`. It has put the files, as expected, in `vendor/phpspec/php-diff/`

I can instantiate the class in one of my CakePHP Controllers like this:

```
// src/Controller/UrlsController.php
// ...

use Diff;

public function test()
{
    $diff = new Diff(foo, bar);
    // This works
}
```

However, the documentation for this package gives this as an example on https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-diff/blob/master/example/example.php#L43 which comes *after* instantiating `Diff` (as done in `test()` above).

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/Diff/Renderer/Html/Inline.php';
$renderer = new Diff_Renderer_Html_Inline;
echo $diff->render($renderer);
```

Obviously the `require_once` statement doesn't work because that's not where `Inline.php` lives in Composers hierarchy.

So how do you instantiate `new Diff_Renderer_Html_Inline`? If I just use it like this it errors saying

**Class 'App\Controller\Diff_Renderer_Html_Inline' not found**

Another workaround I thought may be to change the path in `require_once` so it points to it's location in `vendor/`. But surely there is a better solution?

Comment: That's PSR-0 style autoloading (which composer supports) so `new \Diff\Renderer\Html\Inline` would probably work (maybe?)

Comment: Thank you, I'd already tried that but it gives a similiar error, `Class 'Diff\Renderer\Html\Inline' not found`

Comment: If not then `new \Diff_Renderer_Html_Inline` (root NS relative) would perhaps work

Comment: Ah! Yes, that does work :) If you post that as an answer I will accept it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to refer to a class from within another namespace you need to refer to it using its fully qualified name e.g.

```
new \Diff_Renderer_Html_Inline;
```

Or add a `use Diff_Renderer_Html_Inline` after the namespace declaration to be able to do : `new Diff_Renderer_Html_Inline`